# Fix - Pink textures. why are some of my textures pink and some not?

Tags: texturing

I have made a texture for my character but the texture is missing,
and the weird thing is that the shirt is showing the texture and that's the same opject. I have Joined all opjects with ctrl+J and then made the texture. But when I would look at the texture, only the shirt was displayed with a texture.
[image: The blue Shirt has only a texture]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are my textures pink?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8718/why-are-my-textures-pink)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are all the textures in my file pink?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)

Comment: I would guess that there are multiple identical textures, each with the same image, but not all of them are pointed at the image correctly. If this isn't it, is it possible you could upload the .blend?

Comment: I fixed it: export > wavefront: and than add the UV image again.