# Unexpected roughness in the rendering of a flat surface with Blender render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I made the following object. I use the Blender render engine and the basic configuration of the cube material is given bellow.

As you can see, the top face of the cube is rendered rough, and I do not want this. Is it possible to make it appear as the front face, for instance?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Vincent

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks a bit like Z-fighting. Make sure you don't have any overlapping faces (See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5441/599).

Comment: You are right, thanks! I solved the problem by removing the top face of the cube. Now, it is rendered correctly but I do not see a top face in the 3d view… where is the face that is rendered? (I have checked that no object is hidden on the 3d view)

Comment: It might be hidden in edit mode (Press Alt+H, in edit mode). If that doesn't fix it, is it possible you could upload the blend?

Comment: Yes you are right, it was hidden in edit mode.

Problem solved, thanks again.