# Extrusions causing problems in edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

When I extruded vertices in edit mode, for some reason one of the sides of my 3-D model (the textured-looking side to the right) is creating a lot of errors.

First off, it automatically sets extrusions on the x-axis.
Secondly, it doesn't allow me to extrude planes into 3-D shapes.
Thirdly, I can't increase the height of vertices without it creating a new face.
Finally, it renders those automatic textures to create a grainy black texture in render mode.
I attached an image with the solid object (top) and the rendered object (bottom).

Note: I did not set any textures or alter the lighting on the model. Also, the left gray side is working perfectly fine without errors.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the "grainy black texture" is [z-fighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5441/2217). Some where you have overlapping faces.

The automatic extrusions on the x-axis is from the normal value of the face you are extruding from. You can after hitting <kbd>E</kbd> press <kbd>Z</kbd> and that will disable the guide along the normal.

I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't allow me to extrude planes into 3-D shapes." If you select a face in face select mode(change the selection mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>) then press <kbd>E</kbd> you will have a 3D shape.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! 
Deleting the extra vertices solved the problem and got rid of the z-fighting. (: