# Black artifacts in my renders

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm getting black artifacts in my renders. It looks like black pepper.

I've already re-calculated the normals (they were already facing in the right direction, anyway). You can see the artifacts on the door and the awning:

[image: Black artifacts in rendering]

I'm using v2.68, but I get the same thing in v2.70.

Comment: If you could upload your .blend file, I could find exactly what is causing the issue.

Comment: Z-fighting yet again. Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/blender-render-causes-black-splotches-on-an-object/5442#5442 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10958/extrusion-causing-edit-problems-with-screenshot/10961#10961

Answer (score 2):

The black artifacts are caused by **intersecting meshes**. In order to fix the issue, select the house model, enter edit mode and use <kbd>W</kbd> > *"Remove doubles"*. Finally, go back to object mode and check if you have any duplicates of the objects in your scene, and delete them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What you suggested fixed the problem on the awning, but I'm still getting the artifacts on the post and front door.

Comment: I fixed it! Turns out, I had double objects in my post and on the door. Thanks again, user2926289!