# Solidify modifier causes black artifacts on mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view

I'm new to Blender and I've got a problem while using the solidify modifier.
I'm creating a Minecraft character using a rig and I want do a 3D-Head with the solidify modifier but it looks like this:[image: In Preview]

[image: Rendered]

The sides of the solidified faces are glitching; they should have the same color as the top part

**[EDIT]**
**I solved the problem; If I select every face seperatly and use Remove Doubles UV it works.**

Comment: The issue is called z-fighting. It occurs when there is duplicated faces occupying the exact same space, the rendering engine cannot render faces that overlap like that. Go into edit mode, press the space bar  and do "remove doubles". This is a commonly asked question on this site please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12264/black-artifacts-in-my-renders and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10958/extrusions-causing-problems-in-edit-mode/10961#10961

Comment: I have already tried removing doubles but it didn't work

Comment: It is possibly the *Solidify* modifier creating those doubles, it is impossible to know without seeing base mesh topology or knowing how it was before solidifying. Please edit your question and provide wireframe views of the base mesh and with modifiers, or apply the modifiers and remove doubles afterwards.

Comment: I can't add a  wireframe view because my reputation is to low and I can't apply the modifier because there are shapekeys

Comment: Try to give a bit of depth to the modifier so the faces are not overlaping.

Comment: How do I add depth?

Comment: @Niveauvolll please don't mark the question as solved. Write a detailed answer on how you solved your problem and mark it as accepted instead, so that other people with the same issue might learn from your experience.  Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
I switched into Edit-Mode and selected **one** face that was wrong. Then I pressed Spacebar and used **Remvoe Doubles** ***UV***. Now the incorrect face was correct and I continued with the other faces.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Vertex Group with your *Solidify Modifier*, vertices with a weight of `0` can end up running into the z-fighting issue.

A simple solution is built right into the Solidify Modifier, wherein the *Factor* field (located just below the *Vertex Group* field), can be set to an arbitrarily small value to make sure any 0-weight vertices are SLIGHTLY solidified, as well.