# Blender inbuilt render engine black spots

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I started using blender for render a little time ago and today i'm experimenting this odd black spots/dots/zones issue when rendering with blender own render engine but not with the cycles one as you can see on the image attached.
Can you help me?[image]

Comment: Use Cycles, it's better for pretty much all porpuses.

Comment: Overlapping geometry (Z-fighting)http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10958/extrusion-causing-edit-problems-with-screenshot/10961#10961

Comment: Cycles gives that feels of the object made all by the same material,it looks like clay,and in this case certainly not like metal