# How do I stop extruded objects from overlapping

Tags: modeling

I am creating a shopfront in blender and am running into difficulty when extruding certain faces such as the windowsills and doors.

Is there a way to stop the glitches when I extrude them? Is it best to make a wireframe by just extruding the vertices (what I'm doing) or to fill in the faces and use them?

Comment: What do you mean by glitches ? Generally a simple extrude and scale the face should do the job.

Comment: Please add some examples of what exactly is happening, as glitch can mean anything. Note that Blender is not like a game, and can't glitch per se, as everything happens for a reason or is considered a bug (error in source code of the application).

Comment: For now, it seems you get overlapping faces after extruding them which lead to Z-fighting. You should keep in mind that good model is good topology. I'd say it depends whether to extrude vertices or faces - there's no best way, but if window-sills, then extrusion faces may save you some time.

Comment: [Same problem](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10958/2217)