# How to set color on triangle of a mesh

Tags: mesh, materials, light

I am working on a model and facing some problems. The problem is that some of the triangles have different color and i want to make it same color as the whole model is[image]. In the image you will see that some of triangles are in light red color and the remaining model is in dark red color, so how can i change that light red color to dark red color, one material is applied on that mesh.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: maybe unrelated to your question about color, you also have some overlapping geometry (those faces with weird triangles in black and the pattern that looks like a comb) that will casue z-fighting see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render/5442#5442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that issue by selecting these triangles and clicked the Smooth button on left panel. Now the colors of these triangles are same as other triangles.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be different colors on some faces than on others is a function of the direction of the normals of the faces, and the location and energy level of the lamp(s). Faces where the normals of the faces are oriented so that you are looking at them head on in line with, or close to in line with the location of a lamp in the scene will have a more intense hue than faces that are oriented so that you seem to be looking at them on an oblique angle, or at a point that is distant from the line between the location of the lamp and the part of the image you are viewing.

To get a more uniform color on the material, you may need to either change the lamps, add additional lamps to the scene, or both. Depending upon the scene, you might want to change the default lamp to type "sun", change it's elevation ("z" axis value) to something larger, perhaps 500 or 1000 Blender units, and change the energy to a higher value, too. Start, perhaps, with and energy of 250.