# Odd black specks in Render

Tags: rendering

I've been recently trying to do a render of a cliffside with a lighthouse, water, and some fog. For some reason whenever I render the image, black and white specs will obstruct some of the little boxes in the scene, instead of throughout the entire scene.

[image]

Thank you for any insight and help.

Comment: What renderer are you using?

Comment: Possible cause: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5441/599

Comment: I am using Blender Render. I dont know if I can use anything else because then my render will look different, right?

Comment: Does it look like you have multiple faces in the same place?