# Hard edges in render

Tags: rendering, edges, normals

I've been having this problem with several models and I can never figure out what the issue is.
[image]

Hard edges are appearing on the model in rendered view despite it being entirely smooth shaded. There are no overlapping objects, it's not the textures, I've recalculated the normals. I have no clue what is causing this.

Comment: Is there a normal map involved here?

Comment: This could be an instance of shadow terminator artifacts.

Comment: I looked up what terminator artifacts are and.. that seems to be it. I added a subdivision surface modifier and that doesn't really help, there are still sharp edges. I don't suppose this problem will be fixed in Blender any time soon?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91913/some-areas-of-the-mesh-are-dark/91916#91916 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-to-avoid-terminator-artifacts-while-still-using-smooth-shading-and-the-new-phttps://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34074/cause-of-alpha-or-black-artefacts-in-render/34097#34097