# Unusual artefacts in volume render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, artifacts

I am using Blender 2.82a (Cycles) to create a fuzzy ball. However I am getting this strange ring of artefacts in the rendered image, where the alpha channel shows through - I am not getting the smooth rendering that I expect. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

I have looked at [Cause of Alpha or Black Artefacts in Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34074/cause-of-alpha-or-black-artefacts-in-render) (2.79 - could not find the relevant setting in 2.82a. Also I am using volume scatter, not surface material)

Comment: At a first glance you just have to up the sample to at least 2000 *or/and* use intels denoiser in the compositor.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the suggestion from @brockmann. My first attempt was to simply up the samples. The following image is using 2000 samples.

[image]

As you can see - all that has really happened is that the artefacts have moved ever so slightly to the centre.

I looked into the intel denoising. This is a feature that has been added in 2.81. I used the following settings (compositing nodes):
[image]

Quite simple really. At 500 samples, the following image was the result:

[image]

And this is at 2000 samples (same denoising setup):
[image]