# Weird radial pattern on texture in cycles render, but not viewport rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders

I am having an issue with what I believe is the anisotropic shading on my object. It's causing this weird radial pattern on the texture beneath it in an actual render, but it looks good in the rendered view inside the viewport. In the image, the bottom is the viewport rendered view, and the top is an actual render with the same amount of samples.

[image: Anisotropic shader glitch]

Comment: Looks like the cycles equivalent of Z fighting to me. Make sure there are no hidden objects in the same space as the floor. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5441/599