# Texture stains - UV unwrapping

Tags: texturing, uv

Can anyone tell why do I have this stain on my texture?

At first, the texture was normal, but then I had to extrude some faces, and now I have this stains..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add screenshot of object in Edit mode ? It could be [z-fighting](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render). Also make sure to unwrap again after extruding to include new faces into UV map.

Comment: The picture is uploaded. I've unrapped it after I extruded..and before that the texture was fine, but now it looks like this.. And I didn't extrude this part that is shown in the picture, it was at the end of this path, that I've just lengthen a bit..

Comment: Try recalculating normals (`Ctrl`+`N` with all selected), if not yet. If it doesn't help you might want to [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) simplified version of you mesh. You could pack textures also if they are free to use.

Comment: Already tried CTRL + N, it stays the same :( I've got three HDR maps, for different lighting, an only with this morning light I get this results..with the other two looks fine..The problem is I really wanted to use this kind of lighting, for this scene..

Comment: If it *does happen* only with this HDR then it *may be* not problem of mesh. I'm not sure if HDR map can affect mesh like that, still it shouldn't. What is that HDR map and what is its node setup ? How does mesh look like with other HDRs ? What is material setup of the mesh ?

Comment: I use Blender's guru Pro lightning(demo mode), and all the settings worked fine the whole time, until I've extruded a small part of the object..the material setup is the same as in this tutorial : 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W07H7xeUnGE

I save blender's files every time I change a few things..I'll try to open an old one and repeat the steps and maybe it will look fine. I do click and type really fast, so maybe I accidentaly pressed a key when I was working, and it changed the texture..