# Bliniking shadow on rendering result

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am making walking robot and get a weird blinking shadow on the robot's body.
This shadow lasts only one frame and then disappears.

Blender: 2.77
Renderer: BI

[image: frame 1]

[image: frame 2 with shadow]

Frame 3 is similar to 1st (without shadow).

If any details help to fix this just ask. 
I don't know what information might be useful for it.

**Response to Sonace:**

It doesn't help.

[image]

And the robot doesn't have any duplicates under its body.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Blender.SE. Is the mesh animated ? Is the topology of the mesh good enough, so could it be [z-fighting](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render) ? Also do you use Motion Blur ? (if yes try disabling)

Comment: do you use smooth or flat shader?

Comment: Mesh animated (robot body moving to camera while robot making his 1st steps)

Comment: Smooth shaders does not fix artefacts.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/MhcSQ.png

Comment: I don't know is topology good or not. Is this screenshot can help to understand it? http://i.stack.imgur.com/X0iWs.png

Comment: And motion blur is disabled

Comment: Have you checked for overlaping faces?

Comment: Checked. In extreme way. I have [1](removed front face), checked that no other faces present and [2](recreate face again).
[3](render result)

[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IXtJl.png
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ueUH3.png
[3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dZR15.png

Comment: Most likely you are dealing with non planar geometry. To identify, do mesh>cleanup>make planar faces. See: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/cleanup.html#split-non-planar-faces

Comment: It's magic! It's working! :-) cleanup fix everything, thank you! 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/SxiKE.png

Comment: @cegaton Oops, sorry. It's not magic :-( cleanup helps a lot, but doesn't fix all blinkings :-( 

It's much better, but sometimes still blinking http://i.stack.imgur.com/nhf5o.png

Comment: This is in blender render correct? Also do you use a point lamp to light the robot?

Comment: @xlxs scene rendered correct, except this blinking.

I have only one "sun" lamp on scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since nothing works im posting something that *may work*. sellect the object you have this problem apply a smooth shader in it and then add a subdivision modifier change it to simple from catmull-clark.Then change subdivisions to something big like 4-5.
And check again to see if it works.If this still doesnt work add one *more* subdivision modifier but not simple this time.And check again.
This wont work for sure*

Comment: smooth + subdivision helps to fix it  http://i.stack.imgur.com/7rrJC.png

Comment: @Mike Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit mode, click 'Remove Doubles' (if there are some, it causes z-fighting) then go to Shading / UVs and recalculate.

If it dosn't work there is a duplicate under the object. Remove it.

Comment: It doesn't help. 
and robot doesn't have any duplicates under his body

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Spr4c.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kwq2p.png

Comment: @Mike I edited your question with the links.

Comment: @Sonace See my edit to the question.