# Strange small dark areas on the surface

Tags: mesh

I exported a plot of 3d surface from Maple to .x3d file, then used Meshlab to create from it a .stl file. And finally I tried to use "Solidify" tool of Blender to make the surface 0.02 thick. Here's what I got:
[image: my surface]

Is this normal view? I mean do a lot of small dark areas look normal, provided that the original surface is smooth? If not, then how can I correct it.

It seems, that recalculating normals solved the problem! Here's what it looked like after it.
[image: After recalculating normals]

Comment: Those aren't normal; probably flipped normals seen through because of z-fighting. Include a screenshot of the mesh before solidifying. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by incorrect normals. In order to correct this, go into edit mode, select all the faces, and click on Shading->Normals->Recalculate.

Comment: Thank you, it seems, this solved the problem. I included image of the result in my first message.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept / upvote the answer.  I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I accepted it, but upvoting doesn't work, because I have reputation less than 15...

Comment: @AndreiPetrov - also be sure to hit "W" and then "A" in edit mode and select "Remove Doubles".