# Blotchy reflections on my violin

Tags: rendering, materials

I don't know why the reflection of my violin is so stainy (see image below). please help me.
[image: violin model with odd reflections]

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT USE ALL CAPS. (*really I was not yelling*)

Comment: Can you share your material/texture setup?

Comment: Looks like Z-Fighting to me. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render

Comment: Z-fighting? it seems interesting how can i solve it? I tried to remove doubles but holes are forming on it... How can i attach my file?

Comment: Beside, my shape is resulting on a single layer of faces... no overlapping seems to be ... how can i see them in order to solve it?

Comment: I also notice that is a thing that affects only the reflections if i put out reflection the uv mapping is ok

Comment: I succeed !!! It was a problem of recalculating normals... i did and the problem solved by itself.. thank you everybody for the advices !

Comment: @PicchioPacchio will you please write up an answer and answer your question. I find this quite interesting that it was normals, and I'm sure others will find this useful.