# Part of object not visible in render view

Tags: rendering, transparency

Part of my object is rendering with transparency and I don't know why.I've tried rescaling and normal recalculation. Everything is on one layer and I've no mask layers.
I've also tried changing the clipping settings on the camera. There's less transparency showing with the camera view than the top ortho.
Any ideas? Anyone?

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: Probably that's some form of z-fighting, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render. As it's partially seen in solid mode mesh has inproper topology with (probably) overlapping faces and/or inverted normals and/or doubles. It'd be also interesting to look at your node setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That sounds very possible.I managed to get rid of the problem by adding the edge split modifier. I'm honestly not really sure how that solved it...yet. The node setup is just a basic diffuse/glossy mix so far.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Part of my mesh was rendered in Render View in 3D ViewPort but all showing in Full Render Image (F12) see image below.

I found the solution; simple enough. 
**Select the Mesh in Edit Mode, then go to Mesh Menu > Clean Up > Delete Loose. (Clean the Loose Vertices Left after Applying Multier & Sculpting)**

It seemed that I had some loose vertex which were creating a problem. But somehow they are not causing any issues in Full Render F12. Just issue in Render View in 3D View Port.

[image]