# Issue with symmetry in tex paint

Tags: texture-painting

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAKvQ.jpg
[image]

As you can see, the black is all weird and fuzzy. It's like that on both sides. I wasn't having this problem when I wasn't using symmetry. Any help would be helpful!

Comment: that looks like a brush stroke settings issue.. what are your stroke settings?

Comment: Check this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render/5442#5442

Comment: Can you check to see if you have a texture in your brush? That looks almost like you have something going on with a procedural texture as brush or brush mask. Might double check with another brush to see if it still occurs under the same conditions, as the textures are specific to the brush in use.

Comment: okay I got it to work. I don't know what happened exactly though. I don't know if it just needed a restart (I left yesterday and came back today) or maybe it had to do with the UV mapping. Last time I did smart UV project but I don't remember adding margins. Today I added  a margin of .09 and it's working fine. Come to think of it, I may not have even chosen smart UV project yesterday... But it's working now. Thanks for the quick help anyway though! Man I love the Blender community!