# Render vertical artifacts

Tags: rendering, artifacts

Can't find information on it, since don't know what it is actually.
This is what I have in Rendered Viewport Shading:

[image: Rendered Viewport Shading]

And this is what Render shows me as an result:

[image: Render result]

So, what are these vertical lines?
Seems like something wrong with UV, but why then Viewport shows everything ok?
I mean, I'm pretty noob in blender, so I don't have any idea.

Comment: Looks like *z-fighting* (overlapping geometry). Try to *remove doubles* in *Edit Mode*, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render/5442#5442