# Single sided materials - export to obj with backface culling

Tags: texturing, materials, export

I'm creating a 3D-model of a traffic sign for a simulation software.
The problem is, that within the simulation I get some strange texture errors:

[image: demo]

From the simulation-tool-support I got this response:

> Your faces seem to be coplanar and double-sided. Make sure they have
>   proper single-side modeling and that the normals point into the right
>   direction.

In the screenshot you can see, that the normals look right, and the faces are not two sided:

[image: demo2]

How can I create a material, which is only visible from one side?
The model is exported using the obj format and is then converted to flt using osgconv.

Comment: This looks like Z-fighting. Make sure there aren't any mesh faces in the same spot as textured are before exporting. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render

Comment: Material properties are not exported, this is a modelling issue, the send to be overlapping faces in that area