# Boolean Operations - Why the fuzzy result after union of 2 objects?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to join this cube.

[image]

With this cube with a Boolean Union modifier.
[image]

The result is always this fuzziness in the final mesh.  WHY? 
I have checked for correct face orientation and Scale and Rotation.

[image]

Here is a file upload and screenshot of the Boolean as requested.

[image]

[image]

Below is a  successful joining of 2 intersected objects without fuzziness as I explained below.
[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot including the boolean modifier? Also, can you upload the file so we can see what's happening?

Comment: Do you have faces/objects overlapping? This looks like z-fighting. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render

Comment: I added the file and screenshot as requested.  Thank for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hide object used in **Boolean Union** operation.
As for now you have "two" objects in one place.

Remember to hide it also for render, or apply Boolean and remove it completely.

[image]

Comment: I did as you said I hid one of the objects and in fact yes the fuzziness vanished.  However, the 2 objects were still visible as separated in the collections menu.  if ii made the object visible again the fuzziness returned.  So after do I have to join the 2 objects?   I tried it and it seems the object united and the mesh of the second object (the one below) started from the face of the first object.  I posted an image of this above in the main question.