# What controls the noise patterns generated when faces overlap?

Tags: 3d-view, topology

I understand the reason these weird black patterns occur, i.e. faces overlapping one another. But I don't understand what actually controls the patterns which result. Is this to do with the way blender builds the 3D View? Just interested to know.

Thanks,

Jacob

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render/5442#5442