# coloring circle inside a circle differently in one object

Tags: uv

I'm trying to color a 2d object that consists of 3 polygons, one is having the other two inside itself like the picture below.

I'm trying to color those differently like the reference picture on the left.
As you can see from pictures, I selected them all and uv-unwrapped into a image, then i got 3 polygons on uv editor. So i put those into corresponding colors, but things didn't go well as i expected.

If you look at the second picture, the right ear has a little problem like not fully filling the polygon, and if you look at the third picture that shows viewport in layout tab, it's overlapped by the bigger polygon.

Also when i move around the viewport, sometimes the right ear's color change back to its color but blinking rapidly.

If i'm guessing it right those faces are overlapping each other.
One might say why not move the small face a little forward so that they aren't in same y axis position, but i can't, because I should keep these as a 'single' object, and All those vertices and faces should be in same y axis so that rigid body physics can be used.
[image]

[image]

[image]

****Editted***

I don't know why, but when i loaded the blender file again it shows without when rendered as image. But When I either look at it in viewport or export it as 3d model, the model has some glimmering things or stripes on eyes or ears. I still need to fix it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I uploaded it to my post.

Comment: thanks but you need to pack the images first  ;)   (File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend)

Comment: @moonboots OOps, sry i packed but forgot to save it again. Check out again please

Comment: actually I can't see the object you show on screenshot #2, there are 4 objects in your file: 2 are similar, they are meshes with thickness, there is a bezier curve object, and there is an image

Comment: added old version of my file. sry for my mistake on choosing right project file. @moonboots

Comment: Why don't you make one unique mesh with all these meshes (head, face, ears)? They are currently overlapping each other, which may give bad results...

Comment: It is called Z-fighfing https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5442/2214 in blender ONLY Grease Pencil can handle overlapping objects in layers. Fór a mesh you would have to move inner parts forward or add a bit of thickness. Like with Solidify modifier.

Comment: @vklidu wow! I'd never know there exists a terminology for that if you didn't tell me this... Thanks. I will always keep this problem in mind, and also thanks for another good tip for greese pencil having no z fighting issue.