# Why in Cycles render result has most partly black color, different

Tags: cycles-render-engine, visibility

**File to download ---->**
[image]

=============

After I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, the rendering result is like this:

[image]

But in viewport it renders normally:

[image]

These are my settings:

[image]

These are my sun light settings:

[image]

These are my camera settings:

[image]

Here is the viewport, I leave only one structure to make it is more clear:

[image]

And this is my outliner:

[image]

Comment: There is another object in your scene (or whole collection) hidden from Viewport but still enabled for rendering. Check Outliner editor ...

Comment: If vklidu's answer is not correct, please share your file

Comment: @mooboots I upload the file structure, the files in Collections are all `cube` . I am not sure whether you meant for this? Sorry, I am new to blender.

Comment: @vklidu, thanks, I also upload the outliner, and there should be no extra object in between. Do you mean I might put the whole structure into a hidden object, so the light won't work?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to share your blend file with us, you can check the [File Sharing Guide](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3051/53447) if you don't know how to.

Comment: L0Lock's suggestion is probably the fastest way ... speaking to Outliner - you dont have to share it, you can check it by your self, but yes -you have to see all objects listed ... also you can set "Filter" Outliner to show icons of "Holdout" and "Indirect"

Comment: @vklidu thank you for the information. I have uploaded the file, and put it at the beginning of the post. Would you please take a look?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cause of black artifacts in render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render)

Answer (score 1):

Pure example of [Z-fight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) (face is sharing exact the same location with another face). I have to say quite extreme example.
And I can understand to your confusion ... usually it is not such black.

Each object in your scene has its duplication at the same place. You can see it simply by selecting any object and dragging away ... you can see there is another object.

[image]

If you separate (or delete them) render is almost fine ... there are also overlapping cuboids on the roof at corners (still visible as black cubes at corners also at bottom of building).

[image]

Another overlaps you can see in viewport Solid view too (see glitchy parts) ...

[image]

[image]

BTW ... hunting issues usually follows the same rules:

- isolate issue
- keep as minimum objects as possible to still generate the issue
- try to append problematic part into a new file
- if issue persists you can know it is your object issue not scene setup
- if issue is gone you can check closer your original scene setup

In your case you could find the problem at the first step simply by moving any object into a new collection (or disable it from rendering).