# Why does the material show 'unexpected' transparency effects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, particles, transparency

Some of the trees leaves have issues with transparency, why is this?

[image: render]

The material settings:

[image: material nodes]

Image (by Krzysztof P. Jasiutowicz, [source](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lisc_lipy.jpg) :

[image: leaf texture]

Comment: By looking at your render, I would check for doubled up leafs, as in z fighting.

Comment: @David the incomplete transparency shows a quadrangle shape this shouldn't be z-fighting. Added the edited image (original was JPEG without transparency)

Comment: The Alpha value might not be 1...

Comment: @someonewithpc, close to 1 but not exactly 1 was it (fumbled too much on the node settings)

Comment: @David z-fighting made also sense for overlapped leaves from particle system. After I changed the emission from verts to faces the issue disappeared.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise As it currently appears, yes. Who is going to answer the question? Should probably have been two separate questions.

Comment: @David yes you were first

Comment: @someonewithpc. could you add the 2nd part as an additional answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this particular problem it seams like your shader, and image's alpha are not the problem, but rather z-fighting. When there are doubled up faces with transparency  the z-fighting will not have the characteristic [black look](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21/2217), but rather strange transparency artifacts (much like your render).

To fix the doubled faces, check your particle settings to see if there any duplicated leaves. If there are more particles then places to emit them, then they will get doubled up.

Here is a cube with 8 vertices, the particle system number for both is set to 32. The only difference in the two is for cube on the right I gave the particles some randomness.
[image: particle settings]

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the problem is that the Alpha channel of your image is not 1; This leads to some translucency sneaking through where it shouldn't. To fix this, you can use many methods, but, probably the best is to use a Brightness/Contrast node:

[image]

If you put that node between your image's alpha and the Mix node, and set the contrast to a rather big value, such as five, the problem should be fixed.

Comment: In cases such as this I find it cleaner to use a *math node* set to something like *greater than*. That way the output is clamped to 0-1, and you have an easy way to control the threshold precisely.

Comment: Yeah, that works as well...