# Odd, glitchy shadows (Blender Internal)

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light

Uploaded an unlisted video of it on youtube, happens at [00:05](https://youtu.be/Kt5VM1nvLsI?t=5s).

If you notice, the shadow of the blue shirted guy's head is blocky and very glitchy. I have no idea what caused this. Here are my render settings:
24fps
AAing turned on at 8, full sample
256x256 tile size
PNG, 90% compression
720p 100%

I just need someone to explain this. Thanks.

Comment: If you mean [these shadows](http://i.imgur.com/BpsEGUD.gif), then it may be z-fighting. Take a look [at this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render) or [at this one](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blocky shadows are either caused by a low resolution shadow buffer ***or*** your object doesn't have enough geometry for the shadow to disperse and appear smooth.

[image]

Go to the lamp and under *Shadow*, increase the size value of the lamp. While you are there, try tweaking the other setting as well to get even better results (hover over the tooltips to see what they do). If not, try subdividing the model a bit, notice the shadow the heads casts on the flat chair shape behind is smooth.

### **Size: 128**

[image]

### **Size: 1024**

[image]