# Weird static-y appearance of object

Tags: transparency, text-object

I'm working on some motion graphics that involves making text appear from behind objects and other text.

I was able to get the first word appear correctly using empties, texture mapping, and mix shaders. (I've been following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/jkU9U5BKlg4?t=833).)

However, when I attempted to use the same method, the second word ends up looking like this:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is/how I could fix it? I want the second word (Tech) to disappear/appear behind the first word (VES in the screenshot).

**Materials**:

- Background surface is a plane set to Emission, Strength 2.0
- First word (VES in the screenshot): Text object, node setup:
  [image]
- Second word (Tech in the screenshot, static-y): Text object, node setup:
  [image]

[image]

Comment: It seems like Z-fighting ([related question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces)), which occurs when both words are semi-/visible. Are the letters located on top of each other?

Comment: @MrZak Yeah, that's kinda what I was thinking. And yes, they are on top of each-other

Comment: @stacker Yeah, that's my issue. Is there no way to fix it?

Comment: @stacker But the thing is that I *need* the text to slide out from behind the first text object. I've updated my question.

Comment: @stacker No, I just typed it. I did scale up the other one manually, but AFAIK I just typed it.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Just move one of the text objects slightly along the y-axis. so that they don't overlap exactly.

Comment: @stacker That worked great. If you could post that as an answer I will glad upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both text objects are located at exactly the same y-coordinate (0). To fix this move one of the text objects slightly along the y-axis after that the z-fighting artifacts will disappear.

[image]