# Why is rendering Collada(.dae) models in Blender resulting in holes?

Tags: texturing, collada

When I preview a .dae/Collada model in Preview on OSX I get a better rendering of the model as compared to the one rendered in Blender. I am rendering using Python and use the following command to import the model: `bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath=shape_file)`

OSX Preview:
[image]

Blender renderings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like z-fighting. Do you have only one object in the scene?

Comment: Yes I have only one object. Why would this problem occur? Is there any way how it can be avoided?

Comment: You have duplicated and/or overlapping faces. read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render