# Material rendering fuzzy on some objects and not others

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

Whenever I try to render my scene part of the object remains very grainy and the texture doesn't seem to render all the way. Only parts of the petals seem to render correctly for some petals, but other petals with the same material render fine.  What is causing this?

I thought perhaps this was just fireflies or something to do with my lighting, but my teacher and I have tried multiple things and none of them have worked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.se! May I ask to confirm if all the petals have the same material applied? Could you show its node setup? Is the light coming from the two planes and background only? What's their material's node setup?

Comment: It looks like you may have some duplicate overlapping faces on those petals.  It would help if you could add a [.Blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for us to look at.

Comment: Yes, all petals have the same material and the light is coming from two planes. Here is a link to the blender file so you can see my setup. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzsrqYiEDoeVcDE1ZnZGYUktVTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yep, your problem is that you have a lot of duplicate petal meshes exactly on top of each other, causing massive [z-fighting](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40698/5705).  Working on an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that several of your petals are duplicated exactly on top of themselves.  Since the petals are super high poly the [z-fighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40698/5705) is not quite as obvious as usual.

This probably happened because you pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>(or <kbd>Alt</kbd>)+<kbd>D</kbd> and then exited the operator with a right click (or by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>).  This does not cancel the entire duplication operation, it just cancels the translation and drops the duplicate directly on top of the old one.

To fix this just select and delete all the unintentional duplicates.  I would do this by selecting each problematic petal and checking if it has a material assigned to it, if not delete it; if so right click it again to select its duplicate, then delete it.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help and detailed explanation! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Kit Glad I could help!  If this has sufficiently [answered your question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) you can mark it as [accepted](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkmark under the voting buttons.