# Black Flickering in Scene

Tags: texturing

[image]

So I recently started using bleder and decided to make a Lightsaber, However after a bit of time modeling i found that the end had a slightly black flicker effect, can any fix this please.
Thanks -Jake.

Comment: The screen shot is not enough to go on. We need to see your material setup and/or compositing tree. Depends on how you are creating the light effect.

Comment: You have oeverlapping geometry. Two different faces cannot occupy the same space. That generates what is called Z-Fightnig. In edit mode select all of your objects, pres Ctrl+V and select "remove doubles"

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698 and:http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5442/5426