# How would I unwrap this?

Tags: texturing

So I'm new to Blender and have created an old tv. Its looking pretty good but I'm having trouble turning it into a net so I can texture it. I'm not sure which parts I need to mark as seams. I've attached some images so if you guys could help me, that' d be great.

[image]

[image]

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLsXQ.jpg

Comment: It looks like you have some overlapping geometry and duplicate faces in your model. It might be good to consider cleaning them um a bit before unwraping

Comment: That texture that looks like diagonal lines on the last image does look like Z-fighting... read this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tutorials are outside the scope of this site. There are lots of good tutorials on YouTube. Just search for "Blender UV Mapping" or "UV unwrap" or "Blender mark seams" and you'll find lots of good information.

To avoid being pedantic, I'll try to give you some kind of answer.

Think of it like a papercraft TV or like you're unfolding a cardboard box. The things you should mark as seams are those places where you'd have two different edges coming together, instead of a fold. You could theoretically mark everything as a seam, and have lots of individual components to texture, but it's typically better to have as few separate pieces as you can manage. Or at least to separate it into pieces that make sense (glass, plastic, etc.).

I hope that at least gets you started.

Comment: This is super helpful! I'll check some of the tutorials out.