# What causes these black artifacts?

Tags: modeling

What did I do that caused the face of the mesh to glitch out like this? And how do I remove/fix it? I'm not sure if it is two faces ontop of each other?
[image]

Comment: Z figthing... you have two or more overlapping faces

Comment: Read these links: - [Z fighting caused by overlapping geometry, remove doubles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698) (Alternative answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5442/5426))

Answer (score 1):

As Cegaton said,

> Z figthing... you have two or more overlapping faces

This happens when two or more faces overlap. When trying to fix this go edit mode <kbd>TAB</kbd> then press <kbd>z</kbd> to go into wireframe mode. The darker sections darker than the normal greys are where faces overlap. Follow those to the vertices and move the vertice. (you may have to move than one)

#### References

[Cause of black artifacts in render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render/5442#5442)