# Seams won't disappear in rendered mode even when they are cleared

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

[image]

I've been trying to get rid of the dots to no avail and have noticed that the dots correspond to the position of the seams. However, even after clearing them they still persist! If there is a solution, I hope that it doesn't involve repainting or retopologizing the model.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on. I see a few issues: the chin looks like overlapping geometry (and Z-fighting), shoulders and chest look like there is no smoothing (or no subsurf ) Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of the question and add more information. The fastest way to help you is if you upload your model for others to inspect. Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the reslulting link as part of the question.

Comment: Maybe related: 
   - [Z fighting caused by overlapping geometry](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698) (Alternative answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5442/5426))

   - [Normals are flipped](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3606/2217)