# Weird faces blinking / overlapping problem

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces

I stumbled upon a weird problem while modelling a wall of a building. I started with a plane, then added windows by subdividing faces (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and using insets (<kbd>I</kbd>). Then I dissolved some edges that  didn't seemed important for my model. However after dissolving them, faces started to look weird/glitchy, like they were overlapping. Apart of that, I can't select separate faces, feels like something is covering them. That's a bit counter intuitive for me since i'm working with a 2d plane so it should be impossible for faces to overlap.

When I try to extrude, I get a sort of copy of plane, not the actual extrusion.

All this makes further work on this model impossible and forces me to rollback a few steps, which isn't a big deal, but I'd like to understand what causes this issue to avoid it in future.

I would be grateful if someone more knowledgeable could explain it to me. Please take a look at the video in the link to see what the problem looks like.

[problem with 'overlapping' faces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jXKJ.jpg)

Comment: Try Remove Doubles and search here for Z-fighting.

Comment: ye it seems as you have overlapping faces....Remove double might or might not work if it doesnt you should try and find yourselft what is happening

Comment: Related links for Black artifacts / Strange shadows / Some faces are black or darker than others:

   - [Z fighting caused by overlapping geometry, remove doubles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698) (Alternative answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5442/5426))