# Weird Patterns on Glossy materials in render

Tags: modeling, rendering

I've been getting weird patterns on my viewport render which i am trying to get rid off.
i don't know why they appear in the first place,but i tried everything to remove them but all in vein.

i've also **recalculated the normals** but that too **didn't work**.

it appears that it looks fine in a render,but when i see it in viewport, i see those patterns again.strange. This one is a viewport render:[image: See the base of the bulb]

The bottom one is the final render.

[image]

Comment: Looks like interfering faces. Have you tried removing all double verts? Or are there possibly two surfaces very close to eachother inside the model? Then it could be a viewport clipping issue.

Comment: Have you tried removing doubles or lowering the viewport clipping end?

Comment: Those black artifacts are Z-Fighting caused by duplicated geometry. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render

Comment: Thanks cegaton! that really made this problem a lot more clearer