# Strange pattern in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

I was just sculpting my way through a mesh like I often did by now and while doing just normal stuff some strange pattern appeared when changing back to sculpt mode after repositioning another mesh. Any idea what that is, how it appeared and how to get rid of it?

Thanks for the attention.

[image]

Comment: Z-Fighting. You have duplicated geometry. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698

Comment: Ah, alright thanks. Now that that’s out of the way xD never had something like that before, thanks :)