# Shrinkwrapping moiré-like artefacts (blender-osm)

Tags: modifiers, artifacts

I'm having issues with getting a water polygon imported through blender-osm add-on to properly shrink-wrap on the corresponding terrain.

Here is what the artifact looks like (the black moiré-like effect):

[image]

Here is what the polygon looks like when it isn't shrinkwraped:

[image]

Any idea on how to deal with these problems when shrink-wrapping in general (or with the Blender-osm add-on in particular)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shrinkwrap will move the faces of an object on top of the faces of the target object, making them overlap or occupy the same space. When that happens you get **Z-fighting** errors. The program cannot decide which surface to render.
 (For a detailed explanation read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).

To avoid it make the shrinkrwapped surface be above or below the target surface. Use the Offset option within the modifier.

Additional info in this related link:  [How do I avoid rendering glitches from overlapping faces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698)