# Shrink Wrap Modifier producing unexpected results

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertex-groups, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to add a label to a bag I've modelled and I want it to follow the vertices of the bag. When I try to shrink-wrap the label to the top of the bag it just makes an odd rectangular shape.

I tried pointing the modifier at a vertex group on the bag but this did not work either.

Any ideas?[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the [label] moving in relation around the surface of the bag and not firmly attached? Is it firmly attached to the bag?

Answer (score 2):

You need a high-resolution plane for the shrinkwrap. Subdived it multiple times with "W"&"S" buttons in edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

FFeller has given you an answer for one very valid interpretation of your problem.

You can consider one mesh only. Another interpretation of your problem is that you might just place a texture on the bag so you have one mesh and not two, if your image or animation is in this category.  You can accept or discard this approach.

BSE and other sites have tutorials on textures.  This proposed answer is not a tutorial.

Of course there are other interpretations of your problem.

Comment: note that using a texture instead of a new mesh will also help you prevent other problems, like z-fighting, that occurs when two surfaces are overlapping or too close to each other. Read: [Shrinkwrapping moiré-like artefacts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100394/shrinkwrapping-moir%C3%A9-like-artefacts-blender-osm/100398#100398)