# Shrink-wrap not conforming to X-Axis

Tags: modeling, modifiers, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to shrink-wrap a simple rectangular shaped object onto another mesh. The vertical-axis works fine but it will not conform on the horizontal. Strange as the text in the middle worked fine.
Could anybody help me please?
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131665/shrink-wrap-modifier-producing-unexpected-results/131667#131667

Comment: Hi, sorry I still don't understand. I want to shrink the square object to the cylinder to then extrude it. like the lettering. Could you show me how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Shrinkwrap is doing its best, with the provided vertices.. it can't bend an edge defined by only two points.

- Subdivide the edges you want to conform to the curvature
- Adjust the offset

And.. if you want a less destructive way (fussy clients, etc.), assign a lattice deform modifier to some or all of the vertices of the square, text, etc. and Shrinkwrap the lattice. This allows an extrusion without applying the Shrinkwrap.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface/44820#44820

Comment: @cegaton thanks.. I probably should have made a ref. in the first place, rather than answering ..