# Pixelated error on select faces during Render

Tags: rendering, shaders, faces, error

I have a low poly model and I can't figure out what is doing this. It's not a reversed normal and I removed duplicate vertexes so....?  These faces were the most recent adds to the model buy adding vertexes and creating new faces. there are a little bit darker than the others when viewed as solid.

thanks

[image: low poly blender render error]

Comment: Overlapping geometry causing Z-fighting

Comment: I'm not sure but I think its either 2 faces/vertices in the same spot or your faces are backwards that you can fix with ctrl+N

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces

Comment: Ctrl +N does not fix it it. Removing duplicates does not fix it.

Comment: Running only the "remove duplicated" operator is not enough to get rid of all the the possible overlapping causes. Examine the interested area and see what is causing the overlap.

Answer (score 0):

So it was definitely a duplicate face, but the bad face had some strange properties. I had to delete all the bad faces and start over. I created the issue again by subdividing the edge and creating a new face with the new vertex. Still don't know why.