# Dark areas appear after extruding

Tags: extrude

[image]Novice in Blender, sorry:)

Why do I have this view of chimney on the house?

I've extruded the hollow region. On the video tutorial that I followed, everything is ok with chimney view

What may be the problem?

Comment: This is Z-fighting between possibly extrusion and previously existing geometry there, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render. There is some geometry either in Edit or Object mode in the same place. Alt+H in Edit mode and try to find it or in Object mode

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two faces on top of each other. Try selecting the face (the dark-ish one) and deleting it (x > faces). Is there still a face there? If so, then most likely you extruded, then left clicked or "undo"ed, but an artifact of the extrude was left over. From my limited experience, when you extrude, Blender seems to do two steps... First it creates the new verts and edges, then second it "pulls" them up. If you then "undo" the extrude, it sometimes only "undoes" the pull, not the creations of the new verts and such. If you then extrude again, it may pull up two copies  of everything, or something like that. I am just speaking from my own experience, not from any inside knowledge of how Blender works, so good luck.

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me like the normals are inside-out.  The first thing I'd try is to select the face then ALT-N.  But then I'm a beginner, so after that, I'd be lost.

Comment: Recalculating normals is done with Ctrl+N. Even then note that while those seen on the screenshot are normals oriented inside there isn't any reason to recalculate them since that's another layer of geometry atop of main one and its orientation might not be changed.