# How to Remove Weird Black Spot

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

[image]I have pressed some button and it created black spot that can be seen on the screen. How do I remove it and what is this spot? [image]

Comment: No, it's not a vertex, it's not selectable. It also looks a lot different than any vertex and can be seen through entire 3D view through all other surfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that it was a grease pencil dot, I just selected "erase" option in the grease pencil menu and used it on dot, it got erased. [image]

Comment: (Unrelated to the question) Your model has horrible Z-figthing caused by overlapping geometry. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698

Comment: It's a map and that is how it look outside, it's not supposed to be pretty on the outside as that view is never going to be shown.