# Pixelated Issue In Blender Render

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I have been having this problem in my Blender file. I have created a short 180 frame animation that all works fine however when I render the animation one of my objects has a pixelated/distorted look to it.

I would like to sort this out but I don't know what to do. I have attached a screenshot of what it looks like after rendering.

Thanks, Brad

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know it make sense to you but to me I have no idea what your expected output is or what I am looking at in the screenshot. Is it (the screenshot) a single mesh with a single texture? Is it supposed to be dark? What shape is the mesh? Is there real world equivalent you could point us to?

Comment: Suggestion.  The face count of an object is listed on the screen in [edit] mode.  For example a simple cube should have 6 faces.  Cube subdivided once should have 6 * 4 faces.  Do you have duplicates of faces created by mistake?  Show your UV Map and Output windows.  You can also post your file for others to inspect. What is your experience level with Blender .. 2 Years, 2 Months?

Comment: If you have little experience with Blender, and the file effort recreation time is expected to be small, then consider the following.  For simple projects the 2nd time around of mesh modeling is easier than the first time . Archive/Backup your file.  Then create a new file or new object.  The 2nd creation will probably be better than the first because it will have less accumulated mistakes.  Delete and Replace.  Try a Fresh Start.  No product endorsement intended.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for the help so far. I haven't had too much experience with Blender thus far and only know the basics and some more advanced things. I do not think that any faces are overlapping but if someone could inform me on how to link my file to the forum some of you could look at it and try to help me out hopefully. I have also edited the post to include a picture of what the object is meant to look like when it has rendered.

Answer (score 1):

check out if the object isn't duplicated. maybe there are two objects at the same location.

Comment: Read: [How do I avoid rendering glitches from overlapping faces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698)