# Blender artifacts when zooming out

Tags: rendering, artifacts

I facing the problem that I get artifacts around areas where polygons are close together when zooming out: this is also visible in rendered shading.
It seems like some of the polygons disappear:[image]

This does happen with polygons from the same mesh and polygons of other meshes as long as theyre close together.
I checked the normals which are fine.
It is fine when I frehsly reopend blender and open the scene but after editing the mesh just a little the artefacts reoccour.
I already tried making a completely new scene and importing the mesh but the artefacts also happen then.

[image]

Comment: Looks like edge problems to me, please upload your .blend

Comment: Have you checked the views near and far plane? Does this occur when rendering as well? Could it be [z-fighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698) (maybe caused by a solidify modifier).

Comment: @WhatAMesh here is the .blend https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P3TJo42edrd2tv_zHiU1cLWnWzmQ69ne

Comment: @Leander it happens in rendered shading but not when rendering,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mesh is fine, but it is way too big in blender dimensions, you should scale it down quite a bit.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh I see, as I'm beginner I used a premade generic human 3D-model to model this mesh around and it apparently had pretty big dimensions. Thank you I will keep and an eye out in the future to not go too big in dimensions

Comment: Did it actually work for you?

Comment: yes no more artifacts in the 3D view so far

Comment: @Chris Ok, great!

Answer (score 2):

It can be the *Clipping Distance* of the Scene view and the camera, try to set a higher number, and those weird clipping artifacts will disappear.