# Material at Viewport Shading some lines seem to appear

Tags: materials, 3d-view, shaders, shadows, reflection

I have a problem with my material at Viewport Shading, some lines seem to appear. How can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: Looks like probably Z-Fighting, see..https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces