# Bug with my meshes?

Tags: mesh

[image]

Can't get my meshes to stop doing this and it's quite annoying

Comment: This looks like Z-fighting to me, take a look at [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces) and [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render).