# Areas with no light in cycles engine (even with a light source right next to it)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

So recently I've been trying to learn blender and came across an issue when following a tutorial. There seem to be black areas on the object no matter if I put a light in front of it or super far away. On Eevee, it doesn't have this issue but with Cycles, it does :(.  If I could get some help with this that would be great as I'm a complete noob :).

Here is the link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ELOnZeBz2aZee5takXzCX67cAJsUKH0/view?usp=sharing

And this is what it looks like on cycles viewport:[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces