# Material isn't displaying properly with an Array of instances

Tags: materials, modifiers, instances

[image]

[image]

I am trying to create balconies for a high rise building and want them to be editable. I parented the pink cubes to the peach cube, then made the peach cube an instance of a Plane's face, then added an Array modifier to the plane and set the count to 6. The issue is that now the pink material is showing up as black on the first balcony. What is causing this?

Comment: that is caused by overlapping objects. the pink cubes are being overlapped at the same position with another pink cube. btw your attached blend file is not up to date with what you are showing us in your screenshot. please update it so we can take a look at it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render